# Prove the set is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given continuous function $\delta:S \to \mathbb{R}$, suppose set $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathbb{R}\times S$ is open set. Prove $\mathcal{O}_\delta = \{(t,p)\in \mathcal{O}:|t|<\delta(p)\}$ is also open.

My attempt: construct function $F(t,p) = |t| - \delta(p)$ which is continuous so $\mathcal{O}_\delta = \mathcal{O}\bigcap F^{-1}((-\infty,0))$ which is open

Comment: What do you mean when you say that there is a bound for $|t|<\delta(p)$?

Comment: What does it mean to say that we know $|t|<\delta(p)$ there exist an radius $r(p)<\delta(p)$?

Comment: My question is about its *meaning*. Since I don't know its meaning, I don't know whether it holds or not.

Comment: You haven't used that $\delta$ is continuous that I can tell.

Comment: You know there exists an open neighborhood around $(t_0,p_0)$ ins $O$ but you don't know if if for all points $(x,y)$ in that neighborhood that they are in $O_\delta$.  That is, you don't know if  $|x| < \delta(y)$.

Comment: What is your argument that $F$ is continuous? It is, but you have to show *all* the details!

Comment: @fleablood it would be part of the argument of the continuity of $F$..but that was skipped.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma my comment was about the *original* post and the original argument that made no use of any function $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the continuous funcion

$$f:\mathbb R\times S\rightarrow \mathbb R$$

given by

$$f(t, p)=\delta(p)-|t|$$

Then,

$$f^{-1}( (0, +\infty))\cap \mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}_{\delta}.$$

Comment: You need to interset the last expression with $\mathcal{O}$?

Comment: I don't see why you edited the question..

Comment: Because the definition of $\mathcal{O}_\delta$ starts with "all $(t,p) \in \mathcal{O}$ such that...